# Unable to set nginx with Nuxt + Laravel API with HTTPS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js, reverse-proxy

My application is split as:

- Nuxt frontend website in a repository
- Laravel backoffice AND API in a different repository (same server)

What I'm trying to achieve is setting up nginx into two server blocks, so that:

- Nuxt is served via port 3000 (reverse proxy)
- Laravel's backoffice is served as a regular php webpage on port 80
- The API is served on port 8000 so that the website can fetch data

These are my HTTP configs:

**API and backoffice**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/api/public;
    server_name api.website.com;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header      Host $host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass            http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_read_timeout    90;

        proxy_redirect        http://localhost:8000 https://api.website.com;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.website.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

**Website**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_read_timeout                  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout               1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

With these settings on nginx I'm getting a 403 when I try to reach the backoffice, and while the website works, I'm getting a gateway timeout ("Error occured while trying to proxy to") in any request I make.

How can I have it so that I can:

- Browse to api.website.com and have the Laravel + Vue.js website open up
- Browse to website.com and have the compiled Nuxt website open and fetching API data from api.website.com:8000
- Both of these while under HTTPS

Any help would be greatly appreciated.